# chown: changing ownership of '/etc/sudoers'

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions

I want to work with kusnetes of AWS. 
I tried to install AWS CLI,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

This command:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
```

succeeded. 
But when I ran

```
sudo ./aws/install
```

I got an error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

when I ran:

```
su - root
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

and when I ran:

```
chown root /etc/sudoers
```

I got:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I assume you mean "Kubernetes"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error messages say.

Do you know the root password? 
If so, you should be typing that into the `su` command.

If `su` doesn’t work, see if you can login as root.

If that doesn’t work, try booting into emergency single-user mode.